# Programmatically set text color to primary android textview

Tags: android, textview, android-theme

How can I set the text color of my `TextView` to `?android:textColorPrimary` programmatically?

I've tried the code below but it sets the text color always to white for both textColorPrimary and textColorPrimaryInverse (Both of them are not white, I have checked through XML).

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
Resources.Theme theme = getActivity().getTheme();
theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textColorPrimaryInverse, typedValue, true);
int primaryColor = typedValue.data;

mTextView.setTextColor(primaryColor);
```

Comment: Usually I extend TextView class and I use it everywhere in app. In my TextView class I settings things like default color, font and so on. Another approach is to make a static variable with desired color and use .setTextColor(); everywhere. Third way is to use new Android Studio (1.4) theme debugger to edit your theme. I know this is not direct answer, but it might be a good work around.

Comment: I don't intend to use `setTextColor` everywhere. I want to set the color from secondary to primary for a particular `TextView`.

Comment: can you try to use it as... .. `mTextView.setTextColor(android.R.attr.textColorPrimary);`

Comment: @sourabhbans No, that doesn't work :(

Comment: are you using customized theme for app?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Finally I used the following code to get the primary text color of the theme -

```
// Get the primary text color of the theme
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
Resources.Theme theme = getActivity().getTheme();
theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textColorPrimary, typedValue, true);
TypedArray arr =
        getActivity().obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, new int[]{
                android.R.attr.textColorPrimary});
int primaryColor = arr.getColor(0, -1);
```

Comment: Don't forget to recycle the TypedArray after your last line `arr.recycle()`.

Comment: It works but it causes an "Invalid ID" error. Benjiko99's answer does not cause this error.

Answer (score 26):

You need to check if the attribute got resolved to a **resource** or a **color value**.

The default value of **textColorPrimary** is not a **Color** but a **ColorStateList**, which is a **resource**.

**Kotlin solution**

```
@ColorInt
fun Context.resolveColorAttr(@AttrRes colorAttr: Int): Int {
    val resolvedAttr = resolveThemeAttr(colorAttr)
    // resourceId is used if it's a ColorStateList, and data if it's a color reference or a hex color
    val colorRes = if (resolvedAttr.resourceId != 0) resolvedAttr.resourceId else resolvedAttr.data
    return ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorRes)
}

fun Context.resolveThemeAttr(@AttrRes attrRes: Int): TypedValue {
    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    theme.resolveAttribute(attrRes, typedValue, true)
    return typedValue
}
```

**Usage**

```
@ColorInt val color = context.resolveColorAttr(android.R.attr.textColorPrimaryInverse)
```

Comment: Best answer imo. jaibatrik's answer also worked but it caused an "Invalid ID" error.

Answer (score 8):

Extension version in kotlin

```
@ColorInt
fun Context.getColorResCompat(@AttrRes id: Int): Int {
    val resolvedAttr = TypedValue()
    this.theme.resolveAttribute(id, resolvedAttr, true)
    val colorRes = resolvedAttr.run { if (resourceId != 0) resourceId else data }
    return ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorRes)
}
```

usage:

```
textView.setTextColor(mActivity.getColorResCompat(android.R.attr.textColorPrimary))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the kotlin version of [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050999/58241917#46477727) reply. I just added it in case someone needed it.  Worked fine for me.

```
fun resolveThemeAttr(context: Context, @AttrRes attrRes: Int): TypedValue {
    val theme = context.theme
    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    theme.resolveAttribute(attrRes, typedValue, true)
    return typedValue
}
@ColorInt
fun resolveColorAttr(context: Context, @AttrRes colorAttr: Int): Int {
    val resolvedAttr = resolveThemeAttr(context, colorAttr)
    // resourceId is used if it's a ColorStateList, and data if it's a color reference or a hex color
    val colorRes = if (resolvedAttr.resourceId != 0)
            resolvedAttr.resourceId
        else
            resolvedAttr.data
    return ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes)
}
```

Use:

```
@ColorInt val color = resolveColorAttr(view.context,
    android.R.attr.textColorPrimary)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution for it:

```
@ColorInt
fun Context.getColorCompat(@ColorRes colorRes: Int) =  ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorRes)
@ColorInt
fun Fragment.getColorCompat(@ColorRes colorRes: Int) = activity!!.getColorCompat(colorRes)

@ColorInt
fun Activity.getColorCompatFromAttr(@AttrRes colorAttrRes: Int) = getColorCompat(getResIdFromAttribute(this, colorAttrRes))
@ColorInt
fun Fragment.getColorCompatFromAttr(@AttrRes colorAttrRes: Int) = activity!!.getColorCompatFromAttr(colorAttrRes)
```

**getResIdFromAttribute**

```
    @JvmStatic
    fun getResIdFromAttribute(activity: Activity, @AttrRes attr: Int): Int {
        if (attr == 0)
            return 0
        val typedValue = TypedValue()
        activity.theme.resolveAttribute(attr, typedValue, true)
        val resourceId = typedValue.resourceId
        return if (resourceId != 0)
            resourceId
        else typedValue.data
    }
```