# how to access primary text color in kotlin fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I want to change the text color in a pie chart according to the theme. But when I try to access it by `ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), android.R.attr.textColorPrimary)`, it gives an error like this:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1010036
```

How can I access it?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050999/programmatically-set-text-color-to-primary-android-textview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically set text color to primary android textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050999/programmatically-set-text-color-to-primary-android-textview)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs it, I found a workaround. First, create this function:

```
fun Context.getColorThemeRes(@AttrRes id: Int): Int {
     val resolvedAttr = TypedValue()
     this.theme.resolveAttribute(id, resolvedAttr, true)
     return this.getColor(resolvedAttr.resourceId)
}
```

Then you can access the primary text color:

```
val textColorPrimary = requireContext().getColorThemeRes(android.R.attr.textColorPrimary)
```

Answer (score 0):

just use your color attribute like this:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.textColorPrimary)
```